# Swift ios viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, networking, segue, lifecycle

I am new to Swift and im not sure how I should go foward with this.

I have a table view that I populate with data from an external API.

Then if you press on one item/row in the tableview you will get directed to that items "detail" page.

When that happens I send some stuff with the `prepareForSegue` eg items title and some other info.

But once you hit the items detail page one more API call must be made in order to get out some more information about that item.

So my question now is:

Should I display the info coming with the `prepareForSegue` using viewDidLoad()

Then make the second API call inside the viewDidAppear() ?

My goal is to not let the user wait for the second API call, I already made API call nr1 inside the tableview and pushed that info when using `prepareForSegue` so that info should be ready directly when hitting the detail page.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Call second API in detailViewControllers viewdidMethod. also recieve and desplay info coming from firstViewcontroller just before this second call

Comment: I don't think it matters, the call should be asyncronized. So it won't block your ui process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You display whatever info you have in the `viewDidLoad`. Ideally you can have "Load More" button, which will further make the 2nd API call and update the view with fetched info.

If you want to make the 2nd API call automatically, just go ahead and add it in the `viewDidLoad` itself. Network call should be Asynchronous and should update the UI when data is fetched.